# One monitor doesnt work anymore after Standby

Tags: gnome

I have two monitors connected to my PC. When I restart it from Standby my secondary monitor doesnt work anymore. This also happens when I switch to the console and then back to Gnome. How could I fix that?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. =)

Answer (score 1):

`pm-powersave` runs a bunch of scripts when you got into or out of standby. That's probably what's doing it to you. See my answer to [Why is wireless down/strange after switching to battery or closing/opening the lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65632/why-is-wireless-down-strange-after-switching-to-battery) which MAY help

Answer (score 0):

Still has the same issue even on new Ubuntu. After standby on of monitors not starting up and monitor showing no signal message.

My work around for it (turn off monitors and turn them on after again):

```
xset dpms force off && sleep 2 && xset dpms force on
```

But will be good to permanently fix it.

PS: btw - it's happening not each time, just once in a while (probably 1 of 5-6).